# Как удалить # из url, чтобы не мешал обновлению страницы?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.

На сайте есть кнопка "обновить"

```html
<a class="reload" href="#" onclick="window.location.reload(true);">обновить</a>
```

Проблема в том, что если в url страницы есть hash, то она не работает

```
https://site.ru/page/#openModal
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить?

Comment: onclick="window.location.reload(); return false;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает:

```html
   <a class="reload" href="#"  onclick="history.replaceState(null, null, ' '); window.location.reload();">обновить</a>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <a class="reload" href="#" onclick="window.location.reload()">обновить</a>
```